# Dropdown/checkbox options are not binding on the first click after first-time page load in knockout js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am investigating a bug in ASP.net + knockout-3.1.0 app.

*Bug:* I have a popup with few drop-downs and check-boxes. Sometimes, after first-page load when click to open popup first time, it displays with empty drop-downs/check-boxes. It happens rarely and only issue with popup.

*CODE:*

**ASPX**

```
<div id="campaignSettings" runat="server">
    <div class="action modal-popup">
        <a data-bind="click: settings.Show">Settings </a>
    </div>
    <div id="popupContainer">
        <div id="dialog" class="window dialog-settings">
            <div class="dialog-container">
                <controls:Settings id="settings" runat="server"></controls:Settings>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function loadKo() {
    self.settings = new SettingsViewModel(self);
    ko.applyBindings(self);
    ko.applyBindings(self.settings, document.getElementById('koSettings'));
}

Sys.Application.add_init(loadKo);   
</script>
```

**Settings.ascx**

```
<div id="koSettings">
 <select data-bind="options: messageDropdown.Items, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'ID', value: messageDropdown.SelectedValue" ></select>     
</div>
```

**settings.js**

```
function SettingsViewModel(parent) {
    var self = this;

    self.isVisible = ko.observable(false);
    self.isLoaded = false;
    self.SearchType = ko.observable(false);
    self.ShowDefault = ko.observable();

    self.messageDropdown = {
        Items: ko.observableArray(),
        SelectedValue: ko.observable()
    };

    self.preferences = ko.observableArray();
    self.showDuration = ko.observable(false);

    self.getPreference = function (list, id) {
        var arr = ko.utils.arrayFilter(list, function (item) {
            return item.PreferenceID() == id.PreferenceID;
        });
        return arr[0];
    }

    self.messageDropdown.SelectedValue.subscribe(function (data) {
        if (data == 22) {
            self.showDuration(false);
            self.durationDropdown.SelectedValue(0);
        }
        else {
            self.showDuration(true);
        }
    });


    self.Show = function () {
        if (self.isLoaded !== true) {
            self.Load();
        }

        if (self.isVisible() !== true) {
            self.LoadPreferences();
        }
        self.isVisible(true);
    }


    self.Cancel = function () {
        self.isVisible(false);
    }

    self.Load = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "rest/preference/load",
            async: false,
            context: document.body
        }).done(function (data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Data, {}, self);
            self.isLoaded = true;
            self.SearchType(data.Data.SearchType);
        });
    }

    self.LoadPreferences = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "rest/preference/get",
            async: false,
            context: document.body
        }).done(function (data) {
            self.preferences.removeAll();
            self.messageDropdown.SelectedValue(data.Data.SelectedMessage);
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal-popup').click(function (e) {
        var att = $('.modal-popup').attr('disabled');
        var isLinkDisabled = false;
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!$.browser.msie) {
            if (att != 'disabled') {
                isLinkDisabled = false;
            }
            else {
                isLinkDisabled = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (att != true) {
                isLinkDisabled = false;
            }
            else {
                isLinkDisabled = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isLinkDisabled) {
            var id = $('#dialog');
            setPopupPosition(id, e);

            $(id).show('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

I noticed that sometimes self.Show function is not triggered when popup displayed empty. Any insight someone might have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this code in **settings.js** solved my issue:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.modal-popup').click(function (e) {
        var elementToBind = document.getElementById('koSettings');
        var existingContext = ko.contextFor(elementToBind);
        if (existingContext && existingContext.$data.isLoaded) {
            // do nothing
        }
        else {
            existingContext.$rawData.Load();
            existingContext.$rawData.LoadPreferences();
        }

        // other lines
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few corrections in the way you are trying to bind. "self" is not defined while initializing settings. Please check following and see it it makes sense.

```js
function SettingsViewModel(parent) {
    var self = this;

    self.isVisible = ko.observable(false);
    self.isLoaded = false;
    self.SearchType = ko.observable(false);
    self.ShowDefault = ko.observable();

    self.messageDropdown = {
        Items: ko.observableArray(),
        SelectedValue: ko.observable()
    };

    self.preferences = ko.observableArray();
    self.showDuration = ko.observable(false);

    self.getPreference = function (list, id) {
        var arr = ko.utils.arrayFilter(list, function (item) {
            return item.PreferenceID() == id.PreferenceID;
        });
        return arr[0];
    }

    self.messageDropdown.SelectedValue.subscribe(function (data) {
        if (data == 22) {
            self.showDuration(false);
            self.durationDropdown.SelectedValue(0);
        }
        else {
            self.showDuration(true);
        }
    });


    self.Show = function () {
        if (self.isLoaded !== true) {
            self.Load();
        }

        if (self.isVisible() !== true) {
            self.LoadPreferences();
        }
        self.isVisible(true);
    }


    self.Cancel = function () {
        self.isVisible(false);
    }

    self.Load = function () {
    self.messageDropdown.Items([{Value:"a", ID:1}, {Value:"b", ID:2}]);
    }

    self.LoadPreferences = function () {
        self.messageDropdown.SelectedValue(1);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var settings = new SettingsViewModel();  
    ko.applyBindings(settings);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="campaignSettings" runat="server">
    <div class="action modal-popup">
        <a data-bind="click: Show">Settings </a>
    </div>
    <div id="popupContainer">
        <div id="dialog" class="window dialog-settings">
            <div class="dialog-container">
                <controls:Settings id="settings" runat="server"></controls:Settings>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="koSettings">
 <select data-bind="options: messageDropdown.Items(), optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue: 'ID', value: messageDropdown.SelectedValue()" ></select>     
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: you mean settings should initialize and bind in ready function? Could you please mentioned that what changes you want me to try in my code?

Comment: If you want to use Jquery, its better to use it in ready(), you can invoke with javascript function too. 
In your loadKO function self was not defined.
Also document.getElementById('koSettings') will only bind your checkbox and not button.

Comment: data-bind="click: settings.Show"  -- this was wrong as settings contain reference of view model, all methods and properties inside viewModel is accessible directly.

Comment: You did not push  data in your observable array at all messageDropdown.Items, was always empty which is used as source for dropdown.

Comment: "Show is not defined" if use data-bind="click: Show" because function loadKo() is present on aspx page and function SettingsViewModel() is a separate js file named settings.js

Comment: FYI: everything is working fine, issue happens sometimes when we load page after clear cookie/cache.

Comment: @S.K., may be i missed because it is aspx, Is my code giving you same issue with cache ?